# Disable the base href for just one link

Tags: html, location-href

I have a website, which uses base href tag. But I want to use just one element with the absoulute path. Is it possible to make an exception for it?
Is there maybe any trick? Because for some reasons I can not remove the tag, but I have to use an element, which I can not upload to the server.

Comment: The `base` tag should only influence relative URL addresses, [according to the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base). Using an absolute path should work fine?

Answer (score 1):

You just use the full path :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">
</head>
<body>

<a href="questions">Questions</a>
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>

</body>
</html>
```